# Reactive Spring does not support HttpServletRequest as parameter in REST endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I created a RestController which look like this :

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greetings", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Mono<Greeting> greeting(HttpServletRequest request) {

        return Mono.just(new Greeting("Hello..." + request.toString()));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I try to hit the "greetings" endpoint I get an exception :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No resolver for argument [0] of type
>   [org.apache.catalina.servlet4preview.http.HttpServletRequest]

I am using

> ```
> compile('org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-web-reactive')
> ```

How to fix this ?

[Link](http://pastebin.com/heybvCeK) to full stack-trace. [Link](http://pastebin.com/U9t60NUw) to build.gradle

**----------EDIT----------**

Using the interface. Now getting :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No resolver for argument [0] of type
>   [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest] on method (rest is same)

Comment: You are using the wrong `HttpServletRequest`. Use the interface instead of a concrete implementation.

Comment: Fixed it, but still Spring giving trouble.

Comment: Try adding @Context before HttpServletRequest request? http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-Contextannotations

Comment: Nope none of the "HandlerMethodArgumentResolver", as mentioned below in my answer handles this annotation. I think ServletServerHttpRequest is the way to go...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should **never** use the Servlet API in a Spring Reactive Web application. This is not supported and this is making your app container-dependent, whereas Spring Web Reactive can work with non-Servlet runtimes such as Netty.

Instead you should use the HTTP API provided by Spring; here's your code sample with a few changes:

```
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greetings")
    public Mono<Greeting> greeting(ServerHttpRequest request) {

        return Mono.just(new Greeting("Hello..." + request.getURI().toString()));
    }
}
```

You can inject either `ServerWebExchange` or directly `ServerHttpRequest` / `ServerHttpResponse`.

Comment: I can understand "making your app container-dependent", but what do you mean by "not supported " ?

Comment: The class you were using to get the servlet response was internal and should not be used in application code. This can be also very problematic, since you should only use the Servlet 3.1 async IO API to write to the body, or you'll risk blocking completely your application.

Answer (score 4):

I went deep into the call hierarchy and found that there is this class
**InvocableHandlerMethod**, in package **org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method**
, which has :

```
private List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<>();
```

There is a **resolveArguments()** method in this class, which is called to "resolve the arguments". Unfortunately there is no resolver for 
**javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest** in this list.

There is however a **ServerWebExchangeArgumentResolver** which is able to resolve **ServletServerHttpRequest**, from this I can extract the **HttpServletRequest**. Yeaaa....

So the endpoint looks like :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/greetings", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Mono<Greeting> greeting(ServletServerHttpRequest servletServerHttpRequest) {

    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = servletServerHttpRequest.getServletRequest();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

It is important that the **ServletServerHttpRequest** be from the package **org.springframework.http.server.reactive**

Comment: The class is not public anymore. Was it public in the past?