# Reactive Spring does not support ServerHttpRequest as parameter in REST endpoint tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

The question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361298/reactive-spring-does-not-support-httpservletrequest-as-parameter-in-rest-endpoin). Except the fact that I use:

1. `org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest` **not** HttpServletRequest.
2. The exception is got in test code. Real calls works.

Code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SecurityTests.SecurityTestsApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {""})
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class SecurityTests {
        @Test 
        public void myTest() { 
            //send request to myUrl and got 500 
        }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myPath")
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping
    public Mono<Void> myMethod(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        return Mono.empty()
    }

}
```

Exception is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to resolve argument 1 of type 'org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest' on public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<java.lang.Void> MyController$MockitoMock$606550817.myMethod(org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.getArgumentError(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:228) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.resolveArg(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:223) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$null$1(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$resolveArguments$2(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:177) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.resolveArguments(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:183) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:213) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.prepareAttributeMono(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:163) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:117) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.resolveArg(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 227 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:210) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 230 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You've imported the wrong class:

- `org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest` is for Spring MVC
- `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest` is for Spring WebFlux

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Spring you should be injecting one of the following:

- `org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest`
- `org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest`

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments