# Could not use javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest after excluding tomcat from spring boot web

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

My web service is implementing `webclient` from springboot `webflux`. In the meantime, it is also using `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`in some functions (see below).

```
 @GetMapping("/app-info")
    fun appInfo(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        @QueryParam("printAlerts") printAlerts: Boolean?,
    ): ResponseEntity<AppInfo>? {
        val context = request.servletContext
        val metrics: Map<String, Any> = AppMonitoring.getAppMetrics()
```

So, in the `build.gradle.kts` file, I implements both `spring-boot-starter-webflux` and `spring-boot-starter-web`.

However, our team decided to use Netty only. So I need to exclude tomcat. However, `HttpservletRequest` will be no longer available after excluding tomcat.

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude(group = "org.apache.logging.log4j", module = "*")
        exclude(group = "ch.qos.logback", module = "*")
        exclude(group = "org.slf4j", module = "*")
        exclude(group = "commons-logging", module = "*")
        exclude(group = "log4j", module = "*")
        exclude(group = "org.springframework.boot", module = "spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    }
```

Is there a way that allow me to exclude tomcat completely but also using `HttpservletRequest`? I need `HttpServletRequest` object to get `ServletContext` which is an required argument for a library function.

I referenced this post. [Reactive Spring does not support HttpServletRequest as parameter in REST endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361298/reactive-spring-does-not-support-httpservletrequest-as-parameter-in-rest-endpoin)
However, `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest` is could not return what I need.